# how to update object value in JObject

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

i am using JObject in Web API. Sometimes I am getting incorrect json form users specially for Datetime. So, i want that before DeserializeObject  i can check that value if any error in object value , correct the value after correction the value DeserializeObject.

```
{
  "Pickedup": 1,
  "DATE": "05/24/2018 12:00:00 a. m.", -- > in data a. m. is incorrect
  "TIME": "05/24/2018 06:24:00 AM"
}
```

in above json `"05/24/2018 12:00:00 a. m."` This is incorrect value `a. m.` that i want to convert in AM. How can i do this.

Comment: Is your Json Structure Static? I mean to say all the objects are having same structure ?

Comment: @DebashishSaha yes same, and all the objects are in same structure